# Is there a more efficient way to remove a list of docs from firestore?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this function which will run on a cron job to remove a comment from firestore 30 days after the user deletes it.

```
run.db.collection('sites').get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(site => {
                if(site.exists){
                    let query = run.db.collection('sites').doc(site.id).collection('comments');
                    query.where('removed', '<', run.func.getTimeMinus({days: 30})).get()
                        .then(coll => {
                            coll.forEach(doc => {
                                if(doc.exists){
                                    run.db.collection('sites').doc(site.id).collection('comments').doc(doc.id).delete();
                                }
                            });
                        });
                }
            });
        });
```

This function seems it would be resource heavy, since I have to first get an unknown list of sites, then run another query for every sites comments, where the day the user pressed the delete button is less than today minus 30 days.

I want to try and keep my reads and writes as low as possible for obvious [reasons](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing).

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: The comment is its own document in a collection of comment documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What [@doug-stevenson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807126) stated is accurate.

In addition to his answer, I have refactored your code to make use of [`DocumentSnapshot#ref`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.html#ref), call `run.func.getTimeMinus({days: 30})` only once, appropriately chain the promises and also count the number of deleted comments for logging.

```js
let threshold = run.func.getTimeMinus({days: 30});

run.db.collection('sites').get()
  .then(qsSites => {
      let processSitePromises = [];
      qsSites.forEach(site => {
          // delete comments older than 'threshold' for current site
          let taskPromise = site.ref.collection('comments').where('removed', '<', threshold).get()
            .then(qsOldComments => {
              let deleteOpPromises = [];
              qsOldComments.forEach(commentDoc => {
                deleteOpPromises.push(commentDoc.ref.delete())
              });
              return Promise.all(deleteOpPromises)
                .then(resultsArray => resultsArray.length); // count resolved promises for summing below
            });
          processSitePromises.push(taskPromise);
      });

      return Promise.all(processSitePromises)
        .then(commentsDeletedCountArray => commentsDeletedCountArray.reduce((acc, v) => acc+v, 0)); // sum array of numbers

  }).then((commentsDeletedCount) => {
    console.log('Purged ' + commentsDeletedCount + ' comments.');
  }).catch((err) => {
    // catch-all that may be caused by one of the following problems:
    //  - failed to read "/sites" collection
    //  - failed to query "/sites/$siteId/comments"
    //  - failed to delete "/sites/$siteId/comments/$commentId"
    //  - syntax error
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Notes:

- I've prefixed instances of [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.html) with `qs`.
- I could have used `querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ...)` to build the promises arrays, but this calls `querySnapshot.forEach(...)` internally in the getter for `docs` to build the array, so doing it manually skips extra iterations.
- Error handling is very basic. You could make it so that if a delete fails, it is silently ignored rather than stopping the entire process.

Answer (score 1):

The total efficiency of queries aginst Firestore is effectively measured by the number of documents read.  For the most part, N queries that each return M documents is going to perform the same as 1 query that returns N*M documents.  To put it another way, if you need N documents total, it doesn't much matter how many queries you have to make to get all N.

If you just want to reduce the number of queries, then put all the comments in a single collection, and query that collection with the range filter for "removed" in order to get all the documents at once.  But as I said, that's not necessarily any more efficient, since you should be getting the same number of documents total in either case.

The downside with fewer queries that return more documents is that you need more memory to store all those results at once.

Bottom line is this: it's not likely to be worthwhile to worry about it.  Do whatever is most convenient for you, that also minimizes the number of documents read.  Be aware of memory usage.